# Microsoft Graph API calendarView delta query sometimes returns nextLink even though the page is empty

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Sometimes when I do a delta query on a calendarView I get a result with an empty value array and a @odata.nextLink. I would expect to get deltaLink rather than nextLink if there is no data.

```
Request:
GET /v1.0/users/xxxxx/calendarView/delta?StartDateTime=2019-04-04T14:39:25.2156351Z&EndDateTime=2019-05-04T14:39:25.2158741Z

Response:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(event)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxx/calendarView/delta?$skiptoken=Ria-5ww42ZtO......",
    "value": []
}
```

If I follow nextLink I get a new page which has the deltaLink as expected.

```
Request:
GET /v1.0/users/xxxxx/calendarView/delta?$skiptoken=Ria-5ww42ZtO..... 

Response:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(event)",
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxx/calendarView/delta?$deltatoken=Ria-5ww42ZtOB0Q0.....",
    "value": []
}
```

Is this a bug in the api or is it expected to sometimes get empty pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior of the delta query feature. You should keep querying the nextLink as long as one is provided in the response, even if the returned value is an empty array.